# Webview is not working in Qt Creator with mingw on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am using **Qt creator 4.11.1 with Qt 5.14.1 and MinGW on Windows**
I have to open url in webview from QML I followed the below steps:

Added "QT += webkit" in pro file
Included "import QtWebKit 1.0" in qml
Added below code in same qml
WebView {
id: idWebview
anchors.fill: parent
url: "https://www.google.com/"
}

It is build successfully but when I run the application getting "**module "QtWebKit" is not installed**"
I tried "import QtWebView 1.0" instead of QtWebKit, getting "**module "QtWebView" is not installed**"

I have googled about this but didn't figure it out.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: so maybe it doesn't actually installed? How do you run the application, from QtCreator or as a standalone application?

Comment: I am running it from QtCreator

Answer (score 0):

QWebView works only with msvc compiler on windows and clang for osx. mingw does not support it as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have QT version more than 4.0 use webkitwidget instead of webkit in project file.